# Spring boot application deployed via Kubernetes can't connect to external MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kubernetes

I tried my Spring boot application deploy to Kubernetes, but spring boot can't connect to external MySQL.
MySQL is running on AWS RDS and i tried ExternalName service to connect external MySQL.

this is my configs.

```
# mysql.yml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mysql.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  ports:
    - port: 3306
```

```
# app-dev.yml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30000
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: app-dev
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-dev
  labels:
    app: app-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-dev
        image: registry.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/app/app-dev:1
        env:
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: dev
        - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
          # I tried mysql.default, default.mysql, mysql.default.svc.cluster.local.
          value: jdbc:mysql://mysql.default:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      nodeSelector:
        app: app-dev
```

and this is error log

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql.default: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1517)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1507)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1366)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1300)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

```
# kubectl -n default describe service mysql
Name:              mysql
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ExternalName
IP Families:       <none>
IP:
IPs:               <none>
External Name:     mysql.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
Port:              <unset>  3306/TCP
TargetPort:        3306/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

is there anything missing?
please help me.

thank you. and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Have you tried `mysql:3306` without the `default`?

Comment: I tried but isn't work :(

Comment: are both services installed in the same namespace?

Comment: Both in default namespace

Comment: Why not just configure your app to go directly to the RDS endpoint? The service object of type ExternalName just does a redirect. Also what does `kubectl -n default describe service mysql` return?

Comment: I added return. configure directly to the RDS endpoint is also didn't work.